# Why does WebView -> onPause only work the first time?

Tags: java, android

I have a Flash video playing in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). When the user hits the home button, I want to stop the video. I attempt to do this in my [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i(tag, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
    this.webView.onPause();
}
```

I see "onStop" logged out whenever I hit the home button, but the video only stops the first time. I can still hear the audio on all the other times.

The following hack stops the video all the time, but (A) it only stops Flash and not any Javascript timers and (B) it can't shut down any generic Flash video - it can only shut down objects with ID "flashVideo" and with a hook named "stopVideo".

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i(tag, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:$('flashVideo').stopVideo();");
}
```

Comment: Could you try the approach in my [answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8074896/1023092) instead? Not exactly sure if calling WebView.onPause() in your activity's onStop() is healthy :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `this.webView.destroy()` in the `onStop()` but you would need to reinstantiate the webview and re-add the `WebView` to the activity programmatically since webView.destroy basically makes it so no other methods may be called on a WebView after destroy.

Comment: Will this be much more processor intensive compared to getting `onPause` working?

Comment: Not really. It will probably be more intensive to have it running JavaScript while the user isnt viewing the activity.

Comment: The `onPause` working only once is still an unsolved mystery.

Comment: nowhere in your question do you describe that problem, only in the title. In your question you only describe trying to stop the video.

Comment: My second paragraph of text explains that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i made it work by retaining the state in the BackPressed Method

add the follwing code

```
mVideoView.stopPlayback();
mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
```

this might help